# I am trying to get value from radioButton but something happening wrong

Tags: php

I have tried so many times in different ways to solve this. Every time it generates the same output. I searched in [http://google.com] and [http://youtube.com] and followed many tutorials, and implemented my code according them..Their code runs properly but my code gives unknown output, though their code and my code is same.

This is the PHP code:

```
if(!isset($_POST["radio"])){
    $radioMsg="You must Select a Category!";
}
if(isset($_POST["radio"])){
    $radio=$_POST["radio"];
}
```

There is the radio Buttons

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
style="width: 860px;margin: 0px;height: 580px;">

    <input class="form-control" type="" name="name" placeholder="Name..."/ 
    style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" 
    placeholder="Email..."/ style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" 
    placeholder="Password"/ style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="cPassword" 
    placeholder=" 
    confirm Password..."/ style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contactNO" 
    placeholder="Your 
    contact No.."/ style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

    <input type="file" name="image"/ style="width: 400px; margin-left: 
    200px"> 

    <br><br>

    <div style="border: 1px solid #4C6A6D;width: 250px;margin-left: 200px" >
    <?php echo $radioMsg ?>

    <h6 style="margin-left: 20px">Select a Cetagory</h6> 

    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="customer" style="margin-left: 
    25px">Customer<br>

    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="DespensaryOwner" style="margin- 
    left: 
    25px">Despensary Owner<br>

    input type="radio" name="radio" value="dealer" style="margin-left: 
    25px">Dealer<br>

   </div>

   <br>

   <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" 
   style=" margin-left: 200px"><br><br>

</form>
```

if select radioButton1, it returns a value "radio" instead of value "customer"

Comment: What is `type="cust"` :O

Comment: The Type of your first radioButton should be "radio" not "cust" ..

Comment: if you've indented the code blocks, backticks are unnecessary, and actually break syntax highlighting. Fun fact--if you use backticks in actual PHP, it will cause the interpreter to execute shell commands on your system, which could have consequences ranging from mildly annoying to disastrous.

Comment: what is backticks ...i didn't get u

Comment: Backticks are these -> `

Comment: did I use it anywhere?

Comment: Initially yes, you surrounded your code with them, but I edited them out for ya :) notice the code highlighting looks nice now.

Comment: Did either of the provided solutions provide what you needed?

Comment: yeah but the problem was mine...there was no problem in my code...it was mistake in my sql query..I had to inser $radio but inserted only radio...so the sql query inserted the radio string

Answer (score 2):

Input type cannot be "cust":

```
<input type="radio" name="g" value="customer" style="margin-left: 
25px">Customer<br>

<input type="radio" name="g" value="DespensaryOwner" style="margin-left: 
25px">Despensary Owner<br>

<input type="radio" name="g" value="dealer" style="margin-left: 
25px">Dealer<br>enter code here
```

Try code above and see if that works, also you should use better name values as suggested in the comments of this answer

Comment: same result..no change

Comment: Hey, did you change the name value in the php?

and can you show me the rest your form? Are you using a submit button?

Comment: Even if the form is set up correctly, this won't work because the names are different for all the radio buttons. They should all share a common name, which in his example is 'g'. @AjmalHossain, I highly recommend using names/variables of at least 3 characters for clarity.

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. @Ketzak is 100% right. I will update the code in the answer.

Comment: Happens to us all--You're trying to help, and did find a real problem. That's what SO is all about.

I might also suggest removing the backticks from your answer--I removed them from the question, but that won't show up until it's peer-reviewed. I believe @AjmalHossain thought they were necessary to get formatting, but since the code indented, they are extraneous. It's worth mentioning since backticks in PHP actually execute shell commands, so if a user threw these in when they didn't need them, anything from weird errors to file deletion could occur, depending on what they surrounded.

Comment: i edited my post and gave my full form...still it gives unwanted output

Comment: In your php are you doing

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $radio=$_POST["g"];

or

if(isset($_POST["g"])){
    $radio=$_POST["g"];
}

Your should be checking for POST['submit'];

Comment: @Ketzak Cool, I will remove the back ticks. I did not even notice them to be honest

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and ran this locally, by putting it all in a file called "register.php" in the root of a PHP dev server instance, with the PHP code at the top. In that situation, it spits out the error until a valid value is put in, but I imagine you're handling things differently.

I had to remove a number of strange forward slashes and line returns in your HTML, there were missing < and >, and your radio buttons were all named "radio", but after correcting those errors, the code below works:

**PHP:** *(Included PHP tags for completeness)*

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST["category"])){
        $radioMsg="You must Select a Category!";
    }
    if(isset($_POST["category"])){
        $radioMsg="";
        $radio=$_POST["category"];
    }
?>
```

**HTML:** *(Included entire html layout for completeness.)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="register.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width: 860px;margin: 0px;height: 580px;">

        <input class="form-control" type="" name="name" placeholder="Name..." style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="cPassword" placeholder="confirm Password..." style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contactNO" placeholder="Your contact No.." style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

        <input type="file" name="image" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px">

        <br><br>

        <div style="border: 1px solid #4C6A6D;width: 250px;margin-left: 200px" >
        <?php echo $radioMsg ?>

        <h6 style="margin-left: 20px">Select a Category</h6>

        <input type="radio" name="category" value="customer" style="margin-left: 25px">Customer<br>

        <input type="radio" name="category" value="DispensaryOwner" style="margin-left: 25px">Dispensary Owner<br>

        <input type="radio" name="category" value="dealer" style="margin-left: 25px">Dealer<br>

       </div>

       <br>

       <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"
       style=" margin-left: 200px"><br><br>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```